# Liferay - Deleting folders in Document Library does not delete filesystem files

Tags: liferay, document-library

We have an issue with Liferay: when we delete a folder from the Document Library, with some documents inside, the corresponding disk files are not deleted. They are still in place even when the folder is removed from the Liferay Trash Can, and their size is still the full file's size.

When we delete documents directly, this issue does not happen: files are removed from the disk as soon as the document is moved to the trash inside Liferay.

This is a great issue for us since we are not able to free up disk space (a procedure to find already deleted documents and remove their files from the disk would be useful).

The only similar issue I found is this one:
https://www.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3399338 ; I already checked that the user running tomcat has the correct filesystem permission.

This issue occurs on two different environments (staging and production) with the same configuration.

Our configuration uses AdvancedFileSystemStore for the Document Library and our Liferay version is Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA2 (Newton / Build 6201 / March 20, 2014).

**EDIT:** I still haven't found a solution to this problem, but I was able to find and remove deleted files from the filesystem thanks to this app:

https://www.liferay.com/it/marketplace/-/mp/application/49321947

It lists all files existing on the filesystem without an entry in the database, and let you delete them.

Comment: Which version of Liferay are you using? The thread that you link to is from 2009 and on the ancient Liferay 5.0.2

Comment: @OlafKock we are using Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA2 (Newton / Build 6201 / March 20, 2014